# In Backbone.js how do I stop an event from being passed to parent views?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

In Backbone.js how do I stop an event from being passed to parent views?

I have a view that contains instances of itself. Whenever there is an event generated in the child, the parent also gets the event, how do I stop this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you mean HTML events?

Backbone uses jQuery for it's HTML event handling, and jQuery event callbacks provide an argument that you can stop the bubbling up with: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

```
MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {"click #foo": "doFoo"},

  doFoo: function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
  }

});
```